# Getting AJAX multiple file upload to work properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to get my AJAX multiple file upload script to work properly but for some unknown reason it's not uploading any files at all. I'll post any relevant code and known outputs. Hopefully you guys know some ways to debug my code further and see what's going on.

The HTML / Javascript (jQuery):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dmuploader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                function add_log(message){
                    var template = '<li>[' + new Date().getTime() + '] - ' + message + '</li>';
                    $('#debug').find('ul').prepend(template);
                }

                function add_file(id, file){
                    var template = '' +
                        '<div class="file" id="uploadFile' + id + '">' +
                        '<div class="info">' +
                        '#1 - <span class="filename" title="Size: ' + file.size + 'bytes - Mimetype: ' + file.type + '">' + file.name + '</span><br /><small>Status: <span class="status">Waiting</span></small>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="bar">' +
                        '<div class="progress" style="width:0%"></div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</div>';
                    $('#fileList').prepend(template);
                }

                function update_file_status(id, status, message){
                    $('#uploadFile' + id).find('span.status').html(message).addClass(status);
                }

                function update_file_progress(id, percent){
                    $('#uploadFile' + id).find('div.progress').width(percent);
                }

                $("#drag-and-drop-zone").dmUploader({
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    allowedTypes: 'image/*',
                    onInit: function(){
                        add_log('Uploader geladen.');
                    },
                    onBeforeUpload: function(id){
                        add_log('Beginnen met uploaden van #' + id);
                        update_file_status(id, 'uploading', 'Uploading...');
                    },
                    onNewFile: function(id, file){
                        add_log('Nieuw bestand in de wachtrij geplaatst: #' + id);
                        add_file(id, file);
                    },
                    onComplete: function(){
                        add_log('Alle bestanden zijn geupload.');
                    },
                    onUploadProgress: function(id, percent){
                        var percentStr = percent + '%';
                        update_file_progress(id, percentStr);
                    },
                    onUploadSuccess: function(id, data){
                        add_log('Bestand #' + id + ' succesvol geupload.');
                        add_log('Server response for file #' + id + ': ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                        update_file_status(id, 'seccess', 'Upload Complete');
                        update_file_progress(id, '100%');
                    },
                    onUploadError: function(id, message){
                        add_log('Failed to Upload file #' + id + ': ' + message);
                        update_file_status(id, 'error', message);
                    },
                    onFileTypeError: function(file){
                        add_log('File \'' + file.name + '\' cannot be added: must be an image');
                    },
                    onFileSizeError: function(file){
                        add_log('File \'' + file.name + '\' cannot be added: size excess limit');
                    },
                    onFallbackMode: function(message){
                        alert('Browser not supported(do something else here!): ' + message);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Foto's uploaden</h1>
            <div class="left-column">
                <!-- D&D Markup -->
                <div id="drag-and-drop-zone" class="uploader">
                    <div>Sleep de bestanden naar dit venster</div>
                    <div class="or">-of-</div>
                    <div class="browser">
                        <label>
                            <span>Klik hier om de bestandsbrowser to openen</span>
                            <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" title='Click to add Files' />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fileList">
            </div>
            <div id="debug">
                <h2>Informatie</h2>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                &copy; 2015
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP file (this one seems to be giving some trouble):

```
<?php

for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = "upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Error: File can\'t be moved.'));
        }
    }
}

?>
```

When performing the upload of 1 or more files, JSON returns `Server response for file #0: {"status":"Error: File can't be moved."}`

When printing the contents of `$_FILES['file']` it returns:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Certwell_IBF_9040_web-resized-image-238x238.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpNHgAaQ
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 13052
)
```

So it seems the script does receive the file(s) as expected. The jQuery parts seem to work perfectly fine. The only problem is that the files don't actually get uploaded (or saved?) on the server. I did check folder permissions and also checked the `/tmp` folder (which was empty). Browser console doesn't return any errors. Is there anything else I can do to figure out what's going on and why it doesn't work?

Comment: there is definately a syntax error in `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Error: File can't be moved.'));`. this should be `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Error: File can\'t be moved.'));` or `echo json_encode(array("status" => "Error: File can't be moved."));`

Comment: @EdwinKrause Ye I already fixed that. It was a typo. Sorry about that. Problem still stands though.

Comment: you need to ensure /tmp folder is writeable by the web-server user? I'm guessing its Apache. You need to check if www-data (default apache user on ubuntu for an example). Issue > chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/tmp or issue > sudo chmod 777 /tmp. If you don't want tamper with the /tmp linux folder, you can setup your own custom /tmp folder in your app folder within php.ini config http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to ensure `/tmp` folder is writeable by the web-server user. I'm guessing its Apache? You need to check if `www-data` (default apache user on ubuntu for an example). Issue > `chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp` or issue > `sudo chmod 777 /tmp`.

If you don't want tamper with the `/tmp` linux folder, you can setup your own custom `/tmp` folder in your app folder within php.ini config http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir.

In your $newFilePath use

$newFilePath = `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` . "/upload/";

to define you're full path so avoid File can't be moved error.

Comment: I did make the changes you suggested but it had no effect. It's a dedicated server. Tmp folder is writable (even tried 777). If it wasn't, `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` wouldn't return a value. I think something else is going on. But I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: that's strange, do another check for . if(!is_writeable('upload/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {die("Cannot write to destination file");} for $newFilePath if you think $tmpFilePath isn't an issue to debug further.

Comment: Ok I've found the problem. But can't solve it. `$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];` the cause of the problem is the `[$i]` part. When removing it, the files upload just fine. But each file will (obviously) overwrite the previous one. When leaving it in place, the var simply returns a /

Comment: Fixed it. I have no idea why, but after removing the `[$i]` parts everywhere (which should've worked perfectly fine), the script started to work exactly as expected. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Although this answer didn't actually answer my question, it's a good attempt to help. I also hate keeping my questions open when I already know the answer. Therefor I'm accepting this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the root folder of your website, something like

```
$basepath = "/home/yourWebpage/public_html/";
```

and then use this path to upload your photos

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = $basepath . "upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]; // Here use the $basepath....

       if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
           echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
       } else {
           echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Error: File can\'t be moved.'));
        }
    }
```